# Launch here wego application via intent using street address (No latitude, longitude)

Tags: android, here-api

In my application, I have to use a map application to navigate to a destination. I'm using Here wego application for this purpose. I have my street address with me. From the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/mobility-on-demand-toolkit/topics/navigation.html), I could see that it is possible using intents by providing a data URI with the latitude and longitude of that destination.

But I need to launch the application just by using this destination's street address not by converting it to lat long. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't exist in the documentation then it is probably not possible, also a solution like that is bound to introduce some bugs through ambiguity as there could exist multiple streets with the same name or a slight typo in the input.

I would recommend jumping through the extra hoop of implementing a google maps autocomplete or converting your address to a latitude-longitude form purely because of possible bugs even if the option existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the HERE geocoder API to get the geo-coordinates of your destination and then use it to construct the data URI.

See:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/geocoding.html

Alternatively you can use place ID from the places API:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/places.html

Comment: I'm going to download offline map only in Here wego application so that I can navigate even if there is no connection.

I'm not downloading an offline map in my application, in such a situation I can't use geocoder API because it needs either an active network connection or an offline map.